# How do I write an equation inside the following javascript brackets?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular.js controller I want to select the array number that matches $routeParams.propertyID by passing it in. The below works:

```
$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.all_properties[$routeParams.propertyID];
```

*BUT* with arrays, 1 = 0, so it selects the previous array that I want. How would I pass in +1 to select the correct array? I have tried the following with no luck:

```
$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.all_properties[$routeParams.propertyID + 1];
$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.all_properties[($routeParams.propertyID + 1)];
$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.all_properties[($routeParams.propertyID) + 1];
```

Cheers

Comment: Wouldn't you want -1 instead of +1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You property is probably a string, try add a parse to int before doing math

If you are doing

```
var calc = "1" + 1 // calc = "11"
```

If you are not sure, add a console.log($routeParams.propertyID) and check you're firebug console

```
$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.all_properties[parseInt($routeParams.propertyID,10) + 1];
```

And if you are reading at pos one instead of pos zero, you should substract

```
$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.all_properties[parseInt($routeParams.propertyID,10) - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

if propertyID is a string, you probably want to convert it to a number for the addition

```
$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.all_properties[+$routeParams.propertyID + 1];
```

or, if Brandon's comment is correct

```
$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.all_properties[+$routeParams.propertyID - 1];
```

Note in both cases the plus sign (`+`) before the string that converts it to a number

Comment: it's a number not a string

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your context:

### First issue: add or subtract

Why are you **adding** one? Shouldn't you be **subtracting** one?

If array's *zero* corresponds to ID's *one*, then you must do "minus one":

```
+$routeParams.propertyID - 1
```

---

### Second issue: string or number

String or number?

Maybe your ID is a **string** while the array index is a **number**. In this case, this should work:

```
$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.all_properties[+$routeParams.propertyID - 1];
```

**But**, if you say your first code works, perhaps you don't have an "array", but a hash (or "dictionary").

In this case, after adding or subtracting one, you must convert the result back to string:

```
$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.all_properties[(+$routeParams.propertyID - 1) + ""];
```